# Magento: Adding a Website with the same catalog, then associating products to new Website

Tags: php, magento

I just added a new Website to my client's installation. It is supposed to share the same catalog as the one Website that's already there, but products are only showing up if I go to

*"Catalog > Manage Products > Product Foo Bar > Websites > Check new Website > Save".*

How can I just have all products show up in both websites without any extra steps for each product?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can perform this step in bulk from the Manage Products screen.  Click "Select All" and then "Update Attributes" from the drop-down on the far right.  Click "Submit" and then go to the **Websites** tab on the rendered page.  Make your selections and Save.  Voila, all updated at once.

HTH,
JD

Comment: Also you he can use it in development (programmatically), by using this model method `Mage::getModel('catalog/product_website')->addProducts($websiteIds, $productIds)` where `$websiteIds` an array of websites to which you want to assign list of products (`$productIds`). If you want to remove some products from websites  use the same model, but `removeProducts()` method with the same parameters.

Comment: Nice, that's a useful tip, thanks Ivan.  Would be very helpful for unit testing.